# how do I stop firefox from "protecting" me

Tags: firefox, security

I'm trying to download a bunch of old deb packages. I thought I was almost done, but then I saw a long list saying that firefox didn't actually download the deb files due to a security risk.  That's annoying.
These files aren't even for this system. How do I turn that off?

[image: Firefox protected me]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu bar -> Edit -> Preferences -> Privacy&Security -> Security -> Block dangerous downloads -> remove the mark from the box

[image]

Comment: you might like to suggest restoring the setting afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

1. Type `about:config` in the URL bar;
2. Type `dom.block_download_insecure` in the search bar;
3. Double-click the result to change "true" to "false", or click the "toggle" button;
4. I think you may have to re-start, but I'm not sure.